# How to mock a request to a link in an HTML file in pytest?

Tags: python, html, pytest

I am rendering a PDF based on a html file.
I need to test the context of the PDF.
There is href link to https://example.com in the HTML file and I need to mock the request to the link to test the PDF context. So, I actually don't care about the response of that request, I just need to mock the request.
So in my test I tried requests_mock library as following:

```
with requests_mock.mock() as mock:
    mock.get(
        url="https://example.com",
        status_code=200,
    )
    # render pdf
    # check the context
```

But didn't work out. Could anyone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use "responses" package to mock http calls

> pip install responses

```
import responses

@responses.activate
def test_call_example():
    responses.get("https://example.com", status=200)
```